# How to delay displaying of page content until page is completely loaded including scripts and styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs as follows -

```
<div id='1' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
<div id='2' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
...
<div id='149' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
<div id='150' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
```

The content of divs is loaded through MySQL.
I want to display only one div at a time, rest are hidden. There are Navigation buttons to update the display of the Next/Previous div.
So far I am hiding all the div in `$(document).ready` as follows -

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(
function() {
var a = 2, max = 150;
while (a <= max)
{
$('#' + a).hide();
a++;
}
});
</script>
```

**But, the problem in using this is, until the page is loaded completely, all divs are shown.**
The page appears perfectly fine once everything is loaded.

**How can I delay the display or something like that to avoid this? Also, if possible, how to show the custom wait message, "Loading. Please wait" until the page is loaded 100%, for the awareness of the viewer.**

(p.s. I am tagging html, jquery, javascript, and PHP because honestly, I don't know which one these would be the best to correct my problem)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hide the elements via CSS, and then, after the whole page is loaded, display the first one.

Regarding the loading message, add an element containing it, which you can hide (or remove) as soon as the page is fully loaded.

HTML:

```
<div id="loading">Loading, please wait...</div>
<div id='1' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
<div id='2' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
<div id='149' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
<div id='150' class='divs_nav'>My Dynamic Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divs_nav {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('.divs_nav').first().css('display', 'block'); //or whatever display value you want
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Zzg5M/

Comment: I got the same idea, just after posting the question. Your answer was prompt. I will mark it 'accepted' once the time limit of stackoverflow to accept answer, completes. Thanks

Comment: Does this solution work for your problem, Atul? I was thinking it wouldn't, since `$().ready` only waits for the DOM to be loaded, not the page, but maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Just got back from JSFiddle with my solution. Pretty much the same with a little CSS, if you're curious... http://jsfiddle.net/gtXRA/1/

Comment: @RyanMitchell this solution worked for me, because I am hiding all the divs first using `.divs_nav {display: none;}` [**Therefore nothing is displayed on initial page load**] and displaying only first on `$(document).ready`. If there is any other way, please suggest. I hope, I was able to clarify.

Comment: That's great. I was going to suggest `$(window).load` rather than `$(document).ready()` (since that waits for all the assets to be loaded, rather than just the DOM), or (if you were loading in the data asynchronously) using `.done()` to show/hide your divs.

Comment: @Boris your fiddle is pretty nice. But the problem in using timeout is, I don't know how much time will it take to load whole page. Otherwise, some day, I might use your fiddle in some other purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari: I just made use of the setTimeout function to simulate page load. In fact, you can just use `$('.loading').fadeOut();` on `$(window).load`.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari If you want all the assets to be loaded instead of just the DOM, use the load event instead of `$(document).ready` as @RyanMitchell suggested, just use `$(window).on('load', function(){...});`, instead of `$(window).load` since the shortcut `.load()` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: @StathisG Thanks for reminding me, I had forgotten it was deprecated.

Comment: @Boris Being a medical doctor, I don't have in-depth knowledge of programming. Took time to understand your point. Got it now. Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to implement that.

Comment: @StathisG thank you for your update. I never knew this.